Show Hide Rows Based on formula value in Excel VBA
I have a worksheet, where Range W9 has a formula. Which calculation values are from 1 to 10.

Below VBA Code is working, If I manually type values (1 To 10) in
Range W9.

Otherwise not working.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim allColumns As Range

Set allColumns = Rows("10:19")
allColumns.Hidden = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("W9")) Is Nothing Then

    If Target.Value = 1 Then
        Rows("10:19").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = 2 Then
        Rows("11:19").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = 3 Then
        Rows("12:19").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = 4 Then
        Rows("13:19").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = 5 Then
        Rows("14:19").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = 6 Then
        Rows("15:19").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = 7 Then
        Rows("16:19").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = 8 Then
        Rows("17:19").Hidden = True
    ElseIf Target.Value = 9 Then
        Rows("18:19").Hidden = True
    End If

End If
End Sub

Please Help
.

Worksheet_Change is not triggered when a formula result changes. Try to use Worksheet_Calculate

See the above comment, but your code must be adapted. Calculate event does not have a Target argument...

Above Solution works only for first condition.
If Target.Value = 1 Then
Rows("10:19").Hidden = True.

Please, try the next way, copying the  next code in the respective sheet code module:
Option Explicit

Private W9PrevVal As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   W9PrevVal = Range("W9").value
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
 Dim allColumns As Range
 
 If W9PrevVal = 0 Then W9PrevVal = Range("W9").value 'first time the code is run, if sheet has not been activated
                                                     'it creates previous value reference
 If W9PrevVal <> Range("W9").value Then
    W9PrevVal = Range("W9").value
 Else
    Exit Sub 'first time or if W9 value has not been changed
 End If
 
 Set allColumns = rows("10:19")
 allColumns.Hidden = False
 rows(Range("W9").value + 9 & ":19").Hidden = True
End Sub

Please, comment your existing code event, or modify its first line (Worksheet___Change(..., for instance).
If you did not activate the respective sheet, the code will run as it should only after the second time when Calculate event is triggered. After the moment when W9PrevVal receives a value > 0...

Mind Blowing. Love You Mr. @FaneDuru. You Always Saved My Life. Thank You So Much.
